# Creating a batch file to restart service with trademark symbol every 4 hours

Tags: batch-file, service, restart

I'm trying to create a batch file to stop and start service with trademark symbol. However, I can't get over it keeps failing because the trademark any recommendations or ideas?

Im trying to create a bat file with
sc stop "toxi® Auto"

sc start "toxi® Auto"

then upload the bat file into task a scheduler to restart the service every 4 hours.

Comment: How about starting by opening a Command Prompt window, typing ```%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe query type= service```, pressing the `[ENTER]` key and then copying the lines output, which are relevant to that particular service, into your question, formatted in a code box. That way we can all see exactly what we are working with.